# regex to find pairs in array

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to parse that string:

```
[[abc.d.2,mcnv.3.we],[abec.d.2,mcnv.4.we],[abhc.d.2,mcnv.5.we]]
```

In order to have a key value (JSON)

```
{
"abc.d.2": "mcnv.3.we",
"abec.d.2: "mcnv.4.we",
"abhc.d.2": "mcnv.5.we"
}
```

First I would like to check if string can be parse to make it key=>value.
How can I check the string if it contains pairs?

Thanks

Comment: I tried that: (\[.*?,.*?\])
But it's not enough to have couples :(
btw: I never ask a question if I haven't tried for hours before

Comment: Do you expect more levels of nesting?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness no

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Then you should share your effort in question. Also regarding `.*`, even comma will be considered in it. Try being more specific

Comment: @IsraGab are you after something like `\[\[([^,]+),([^\]]+)],\[([^,]+),([^\]]+)],\[([^,]+),([^\]]+)\]\]` ? Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/GReD6H/1/). Substitute with `{\n"\1": "\2",\n"\3": "\4",\n"\5": "\6",\n}`

Comment: No: I have updated the regex you sent with the actual string I have to parse. The string I post here is an example but the real string is a lot bigger than this one:
https://regex101.com/r/GReD6H/2/

Comment: Then you will need a loop as recursion is not supported in Javascript regex.

Comment: Any reason you're using regex specifically? Cant you parse it as a 2-dimensional array and use javascript to check for duplicates? `[["abc.d.2", "mcnv.3.we"], ["abec.d.2", "mcnv.4.we"], ["abhc.d.2", "mcnv.5.we"]]`

Comment: @ Arye Dov Eidelman, The string comes from websocket notication, I don't know how the data in socket will look like so I would like to check which regex match the string in order to send it to the desired function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Approach 1:

**Idea:**

- Update the regex to have more specific characters. In your case, alphanumeric and period.
- Get all matching elements from string.
- All odd values are keys and even matches are values.
- Loop over matches and create an object.

```js
const str = "[[abc.d.2,mcnv.3.we],[abec.d.2,mcnv.4.we],[abhc.d.2,mcnv.5.we]]";
const matches = str.match(/[\w\.\d]+/gi);

const output = {};

for(var i = 0; i< matches.length; i+=2) {
  output[matches[i]] = matches[i+1];
}

console.log(output)
```

---

#### Approach 2:

**Idea:**

- Write a regex to capture each individual group: `[...:...]`
- Then eliminate braces `[` and `]`.
- Split string using comma `,`.
- First part is your key. Second is your value.

```js
const str = "[[abc.d.2,mcnv.3.we],[abec.d.2,mcnv.4.we],[abhc.d.2,mcnv.5.we]]";
const matches = str.match(/\[([\w\d\.,]*)\]/gi);
const output = matches.reduce((obj, match) => {
  const parts = match.substring(1, match.length - 1).split(',');
  obj[parts[0]] = parts[1];
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

In above approach, you can also include [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). The iteration can be bit confusing initially, but you can try.

```js
const str = "[[abc.d.2,mcnv.3.we],[abec.d.2,mcnv.4.we],[abhc.d.2,mcnv.5.we]]";
const matches = str.match(/\[([\w\d\.,]*)\]/gi);
const output = matches.reduce((obj, match) => {
  const parts = match.substring(1, match.length - 1).split(',');
  obj.set(...parts)
  return obj;
}, new Map())

for (const [k, v] of output.entries()) {
  console.log(`Key: ${k}, value: ${v}`)
}
```

Comment: Very nice. That's a lot better than what I have, but I would like to be able to know if it's matching the pairs at the regex. You're dealing with it in the loop

Comment: @IsraGab you can do that as well. But that will take more profession. You can have a regex to match text between `[]` and then split it using string. If you want, i can add snippet tomorrow.

Comment: @ Rajesh, Yes please. I don't care about profession, but maybe next time I will have 3 elements in each sub arrays, then I will send the string to the matching function to create the object. In the current solution the _2_ is hard coded, need to be a parameter in a function call

Comment: I also have another problem with your regex. It doesn't check the *[[* *]]*, So I can have a simple string it will also match:abc.d.2,mcnv.3.we,[abec.d.2,mcnv.4.we,abhc.d.2,mcnv.5.we

Comment: [`\w` character class includes `\d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes)

Comment: @IsraGab I have updated my answer with discussed approach. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Parse the array as JSON, iterate over the array, adding entries to the target object as you go, watch out for duplicate keys:

```
let dict_target = {}; // The target dictionary, 
let src, arysrc, proceed = false;

try {
    src = "[[abc.d.2,mcnv.3.we],[abec.d.2,mcnv.4.we],[abhc.d.2,mcnv.5.we]]"
                  .replace(/,/g, '","')
                  .replace(/\]","\[/g, '"],["')
                  .replace(/^\[\[/, '[["')
                  .replace(/\]\]$/, '"]]')
             ;
    arysrc = JSON.parse(src);
    proceed = true; // Could parse the data, can carry on with processing the data
} catch (e) {
    console.log(`Source data unparseable, error '${e.message}'.`);
} 

if (proceed) {
    arysrc.forEach ( (a_item, n_idx) => {
        if (dict_target.hasOwnProperty(a_item[0])) {
           // add any tests and processing for duplicate keys/value pairs here  
           if (typeof dict_target[a_item[0]] === "string") {
               dict_target[a_item[0]] = [ dict_target[a_item[0]] ];
           }
           dict_target[a_item[0]].push(a_item[1]);
        }
        else {
           dict_target[a_item[0]] = a_item[1];
        }
    });
 } // if -- proceed
```

Comment: I don't have the _'_ you added in the string. I can't use the JSON.parse function.
Also, I don't want to iterate the object, but knows if I can parse it before

Comment: @IsraGab I corrected the solution. If parsing succeeds, you'll know, that you can parse it. You could test that before using a regex. Using them as a stand-in for parsers tends to make them complicated and hard to maintain, so I'd try to avoid this use case, but your setting may be different, of course.

Comment: Yes. I'm testing your solution right now. I would like to be able to check the string first in order to know if I can parse it, but maybe you're right to manipulate the string so I can parse it.

Comment: Would it be cleaner to just replace each key/value in the string with quotes, instead of multiple replacements? `src.replace(/([\w\.]+)/,'"$1"');`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the [`g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) global flag. It's still valid. `src.replace(/([\w\.]+)/g,'"$1"');`

Comment: @SunnyPatel Regex are notoriously hard to maintain, so I prefer to keep them as readable (YMMV in fleshing out the concept, of course) as possible, even if it comes with a performance penalty. If the latter proves to be an issue, optimizations are usually straightforward.

Comment: I disagree if you are suggesting that one of our expressions are difficult to read and/or maintain. They are both pretty straight forward in my opinion. But hey, practice makes perfect, right? :)

Comment: @SunnyPatel We'll revisit the subject 3 months from now ... ;) As I wrote, whatever works.

Answer (score 1):

My coding golf solution...

```
const parse = (str) => {
    let obj = {};
    str.replace(
        /\[([^\[,]+),([^\],]+)\]/g,
        (m, k, v) => obj[k] = v
    );
    return obj;
};
```

Advantages:

- More Permissive of arbitrary chars
- More Tolerant of missing values
- Avoids disposable objects for GC

Disadvantages:

- More Permissive of arbitrary chars!
- This is not a proper parser...
- Does not have context, just [key,val]

I actually wanted to post the following as my answer... but I think it'll get me in trouble :P

```
const parse=(str,obj={})=>
!str.replace(/\[([^\[,]+),([^\],]+)\]/g,(m,k,v)=>obj[k]=v)||obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code which validates the string first and outputs the result. Not at all optimal but does the task just fine.

```js
var string = '[[abc.d.2,mcnv.3.we],[abec.d.2,mcnv.4.we],[abhc.d.2,mcnv.5.we]]';
var result = (/^\[(\[.*\..*\..*\,.*\..*\..*\]\,)*\[(.*\..*\..*\,.*\..*\..*)\]\]$/g).exec(string);
if (result) {
  var r1 = result[1].replace(/\[|\]/g, '').split(',');
  var r2 = result[2].split(',');
  var output = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < r1.length -1; i +=2) {
    output[r1[i]] = r1[i+1];
  }
  output[r2[0]] = r2[1];

  console.log(output);
} else {
  console.log('invalid string');
}
```

Comment: Your Regular Expression is [pretty heavy on the backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) with those greedy `.*`'s.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I mentioned its not an optimal solution :)  Performance wouldn't matter if you are parsing a small string. It would be a different case parsing huge CSVs with logic like this though.